# Image Processing Median Filter in C

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, file, image, memory-management

I am attempting to perform [Median Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter) with size 3 x 3 in C language. The function `MedianFilter33` has been implemented as follows.

**The experimental implementation**

- The basic structures:

  ```
  typedef struct RGB
  {
      unsigned char R, G, B;
  } RGB;

  typedef struct BMPIMAGE
  {
      char FILENAME[MAX_PATH];

      unsigned int XSIZE;
      unsigned int YSIZE;
      unsigned char FILLINGBYTE;
      unsigned char *IMAGE_DATA;
  } BMPIMAGE;

  typedef struct RGBIMAGE
  {
      unsigned int XSIZE;
      unsigned int YSIZE;
      RGB *IMAGE_DATA;
  } RGBIMAGE;
  ```
- `MedianFilter33` function implementation:

  ```
  RGB *MedianFilter33(const RGB *image,const int xsize,const int ysize)
  {
      RGB *output;
      output = (RGB*)malloc(xsize * ysize * sizeof(RGB));
      if (output == NULL)
      {     
          printf("Memory allocation error!");
          return NULL;
      }
      for(long long int i = 0; i <(xsize * ysize); i++)
      {
          if( (i < xsize) || ( (i % xsize) == 0) || ( ((i + 1) % xsize) == 0) || (i >= (xsize*(ysize-1))))
          {
              output[i].R = image[i].R;
              output[i].G = image[i].G;
              output[i].B = image[i].B;
          }    
          else
          {
              unsigned char *sort_array;
              sort_array = (unsigned char*)malloc(9 * sizeof(unsigned char));
              //    R channel sorting
              sort_array[0] = image[i-xsize-1].R;
              sort_array[1] = image[i-xsize].R;
              sort_array[2] = image[i-xsize+1].R;
              sort_array[3] = image[i-1].R;
              sort_array[4] = image[i].R;
              sort_array[5] = image[i+1].R;
              sort_array[6] = image[i+xsize-1].R;
              sort_array[7] = image[i+xsize].R;
              sort_array[8] = image[i+xsize+1].R;
              sort_array = bubble_sort_uchar(sort_array,9,0);
              output[i].R = sort_array[4];
              //    G channel sorting
              sort_array[0] = image[i-xsize-1].G;
              sort_array[1] = image[i-xsize].G;    
              sort_array[2] = image[i-xsize+1].G;
              sort_array[3] = image[i-1].G;        
              sort_array[4] = image[i].G;        
              sort_array[5] = image[i+1].G;        
              sort_array[6] = image[i+xsize-1].G;
              sort_array[7] = image[i+xsize].G;    
              sort_array[8] = image[i+xsize+1].G;
              bubble_sort_uchar(sort_array,9,0);
              output[i].G = sort_array[4];
              //    B channel sorting
              sort_array[0] = image[i-xsize-1].B;
              sort_array[1] = image[i-xsize].B;    
              sort_array[2] = image[i-xsize+1].B;
              sort_array[3] = image[i-1].B;        
              sort_array[4] = image[i].B;        
              sort_array[5] = image[i+1].B;        
              sort_array[6] = image[i+xsize-1].B;
              sort_array[7] = image[i+xsize].B;    
              sort_array[8] = image[i+xsize+1].B;
              bubble_sort_uchar(sort_array,9,0);
              output[i].B = sort_array[4];
          }
      }
      return output;
  }
  ```

**Full Testing Code**

In order to test `MedianFilter33` function implementation above, a tiny `bmp` image read / write framework has been performed.

```
/* Develop by Jimmy Hu */

#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_PATH 256
#define FILE_ROOT_PATH "./"

#define True true
#define False false

typedef struct RGB
{
    unsigned char R, G, B;
} RGB;

typedef struct BMPIMAGE
{
    char FILENAME[MAX_PATH];
    
    unsigned int XSIZE;
    unsigned int YSIZE;
    unsigned char FILLINGBYTE;
    unsigned char *IMAGE_DATA;
} BMPIMAGE;

typedef struct RGBIMAGE
{
    unsigned int XSIZE;
    unsigned int YSIZE;
    RGB *IMAGE_DATA;
} RGBIMAGE;

RGB *MedianFilter33(const RGB*, const int x, const int y);

RGB *raw_image_to_array(const unsigned char *image, const int xsize, const int ysize);

unsigned long bmp_read_x_size(const char *filename, const bool extension);

unsigned long bmp_read_y_size(const char *filename, const bool extension);

char bmp_read(unsigned char *image, const int xsize, const int ysize, const char *filename, const bool extension);

BMPIMAGE bmp_file_read(const char *filename, const bool extension);

int bmp_write(const unsigned char *image, const int xsize, const int ysize, const char *filename);

unsigned char *array_to_raw_image(const RGB* InputData, const int xsize, const int ysize);

unsigned char bmp_filling_byte_calc(const unsigned int xsize);

unsigned char *bubble_sort_uchar(   const unsigned char *data_input,
                                    const unsigned long long int data_input_count,
                                    const bool mode);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("BMP image file name:(ex:test): ");
    char *FilenameString;
    FilenameString = (char*)malloc( MAX_PATH * sizeof(char) );
    scanf("%s",FilenameString);
    BMPIMAGE BMPImage1;
    BMPImage1 = bmp_file_read(FilenameString,false);
    free(FilenameString);
    printf("%s\n",BMPImage1.FILENAME);
    
    if(BMPImage1.IMAGE_DATA == NULL)
    {    
        printf("Image contents error!");
        return -1;
    }        
    
    RGBIMAGE RGBImage1;
    RGBImage1.XSIZE = BMPImage1.XSIZE;
    RGBImage1.YSIZE = BMPImage1.YSIZE;
    RGBImage1.IMAGE_DATA = (RGB*)malloc(RGBImage1.XSIZE * RGBImage1.YSIZE * sizeof(RGB));
    if (RGBImage1.IMAGE_DATA == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation error!");
        return -1;
    }

    RGBImage1.IMAGE_DATA = raw_image_to_array(BMPImage1.IMAGE_DATA, BMPImage1.XSIZE, BMPImage1.YSIZE);
    
    bmp_write(array_to_raw_image(MedianFilter33(RGBImage1.IMAGE_DATA,RGBImage1.XSIZE, RGBImage1.YSIZE), RGBImage1.XSIZE, RGBImage1.YSIZE), BMPImage1.XSIZE, BMPImage1.YSIZE, "MedianFilterOutput");
    
    return 0;
}

RGB *MedianFilter33(const RGB *image,const int xsize,const int ysize)
{
    RGB *output;
    output = (RGB*)malloc(xsize * ysize * sizeof(RGB));
    if (output == NULL)
    {     
        printf("Memory allocation error!");
        return NULL;
    }
    for(long long int i = 0; i <(xsize * ysize); i++)
    {
        if( (i < xsize) || ( (i % xsize) == 0) || ( ((i + 1) % xsize) == 0) || (i >= (xsize*(ysize-1))))
        {
            output[i].R = image[i].R;
            output[i].G = image[i].G;
            output[i].B = image[i].B;
        }    
        else
        {
            unsigned char *sort_array;
            sort_array = (unsigned char*)malloc(9 * sizeof(unsigned char));
            //    R channel sorting
            sort_array[0] = image[i-xsize-1].R;
            sort_array[1] = image[i-xsize].R;
            sort_array[2] = image[i-xsize+1].R;
            sort_array[3] = image[i-1].R;
            sort_array[4] = image[i].R;
            sort_array[5] = image[i+1].R;
            sort_array[6] = image[i+xsize-1].R;
            sort_array[7] = image[i+xsize].R;
            sort_array[8] = image[i+xsize+1].R;
            sort_array = bubble_sort_uchar(sort_array,9,0);
            output[i].R = sort_array[4];
            //    G channel sorting
            sort_array[0] = image[i-xsize-1].G;
            sort_array[1] = image[i-xsize].G;    
            sort_array[2] = image[i-xsize+1].G;
            sort_array[3] = image[i-1].G;        
            sort_array[4] = image[i].G;        
            sort_array[5] = image[i+1].G;        
            sort_array[6] = image[i+xsize-1].G;
            sort_array[7] = image[i+xsize].G;    
            sort_array[8] = image[i+xsize+1].G;
            bubble_sort_uchar(sort_array,9,0);
            output[i].G = sort_array[4];
            //    B channel sorting
            sort_array[0] = image[i-xsize-1].B;
            sort_array[1] = image[i-xsize].B;    
            sort_array[2] = image[i-xsize+1].B;
            sort_array[3] = image[i-1].B;        
            sort_array[4] = image[i].B;        
            sort_array[5] = image[i+1].B;        
            sort_array[6] = image[i+xsize-1].B;
            sort_array[7] = image[i+xsize].B;    
            sort_array[8] = image[i+xsize+1].B;
            bubble_sort_uchar(sort_array,9,0);
            output[i].B = sort_array[4];
        }
    }
    return output;
}

RGB *raw_image_to_array(const unsigned char *image, const int xsize, const int ysize)
{
    RGB *output;
    output = (RGB*)malloc(xsize * ysize * sizeof(RGB));
    if(output == NULL)
    {    
        printf("Memory allocation error!");
        return NULL;
    }        
    unsigned char FillingByte;
    FillingByte = bmp_filling_byte_calc(xsize);
    for(int y = 0;y<ysize;y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0;x<xsize;x++)
        {
            output[y*xsize + x].R =
            image[3*(y * xsize + x) + y * FillingByte + 2];
            output[y*xsize + x].G =
            image[3*(y * xsize + x) + y * FillingByte + 1];
            output[y*xsize + x].B =
            image[3*(y * xsize + x) + y * FillingByte + 0];
        }
    }
    return output;
}

//----bmp_read_x_size function----
unsigned long bmp_read_x_size(const char *filename, const bool extension)
{
    char fname_bmp[MAX_PATH];
    if(extension == false)
    {    
        sprintf(fname_bmp, "%s.bmp", filename);
    }        
    else
    {    
        strcpy(fname_bmp,filename);
    }    
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(fname_bmp, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) 
    {     
        printf("Fail to read file!\n");
        return -1;
    }             
    unsigned char header[54];
    fread(header, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, fp);
    unsigned long output;
    output = header[18] + (header[19] << 8) + ( header[20] << 16) + ( header[21] << 24);
    fclose(fp);
    return output;
}

//---- bmp_read_y_size function ----
unsigned long bmp_read_y_size(const char *filename, const bool extension)
{
    char fname_bmp[MAX_PATH];
    if(extension == false)
    {    
        sprintf(fname_bmp, "%s.bmp", filename);
    }        
    else
    {    
        strcpy(fname_bmp,filename);
    }    
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(fname_bmp, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Fail to read file!\n");
        return -1;
    }             
    unsigned char header[54];
    fread(header, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, fp);
    unsigned long output; 
    output= header[22] + (header[23] << 8) + ( header[24] << 16) + ( header[25] << 24);
    fclose(fp);
    return output;
}

//---- bmp_file_read function ---- 
char bmp_read(unsigned char *image, const int xsize, const int ysize, const char *filename, const bool extension)
{
    char fname_bmp[MAX_PATH];
    if(extension == false)
    {    
        sprintf(fname_bmp, "%s.bmp", filename);
    }        
    else
    {    
        strcpy(fname_bmp,filename);
    }    
    unsigned char filling_bytes;
    filling_bytes = bmp_filling_byte_calc(xsize);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(fname_bmp, "rb");
    if (fp==NULL)
    {     
        printf("Fail to read file!\n");
        return -1;
    }             
    unsigned char header[54];
    fread(header, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, fp);
    fread(image, sizeof(unsigned char), (size_t)(long)(xsize * 3 + filling_bytes)*ysize, fp);
    fclose(fp); 
    return 0;
}

BMPIMAGE bmp_file_read(const char *filename, const bool extension)
{
    BMPIMAGE output;
    stpcpy(output.FILENAME, "");
    output.XSIZE = 0;
    output.YSIZE = 0;
    output.IMAGE_DATA = NULL;
    if(filename == NULL)
    {    
        printf("Path is null\n");
        return output;
    }
    char fname_bmp[MAX_PATH];
    if(extension == false)
    {
        sprintf(fname_bmp, "%s.bmp", filename);
    }
    else
    {    
        strcpy(fname_bmp,filename);
    }    
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(fname_bmp, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {     
        printf("Fail to read file!\n");
        return output;
    }             
    stpcpy(output.FILENAME, fname_bmp);
    output.XSIZE = (unsigned int)bmp_read_x_size(output.FILENAME,true);
    output.YSIZE = (unsigned int)bmp_read_y_size(output.FILENAME,true);
    if( (output.XSIZE == -1) || (output.YSIZE == -1) )
    {     
        printf("Fail to fetch information of image!");
        return output;
    }        
    else
    {     
        printf("Width of the input image: %d\n",output.XSIZE);
        printf("Height of the input image: %d\n",output.YSIZE);
        printf("Size of the input image(Byte): %d\n",(size_t)output.XSIZE * output.YSIZE * 3);
        output.FILLINGBYTE = bmp_filling_byte_calc(output.XSIZE);
        output.IMAGE_DATA = (unsigned char*)malloc((output.XSIZE * 3 + output.FILLINGBYTE) * output.YSIZE * sizeof(unsigned char));
        if (output.IMAGE_DATA == NULL)
        { 
            printf("Memory allocation error!");
            return output;
        }     
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < ((output.XSIZE * 3 + output.FILLINGBYTE) * output.YSIZE);i++)
            {
                output.IMAGE_DATA[i] = 255;
            }
            bmp_read(output.IMAGE_DATA, output.XSIZE, output.YSIZE, output.FILENAME, true);
        }
    }    
    return output;
}

//----bmp_write function---- 
int bmp_write(const unsigned char *image, const int xsize, const int ysize, const char *filename) 
{
    unsigned char FillingByte;
    FillingByte = bmp_filling_byte_calc(xsize);
    unsigned char header[54] =
    {
    0x42, 0x4d, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    54, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 24, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0                        
    };                                
    unsigned long file_size = (long)xsize * (long)ysize * 3 + 54;
    unsigned long width, height;
    char fname_bmp[MAX_PATH];
    header[2] = (unsigned char)(file_size &0x000000ff);
    header[3] = (file_size >> 8) & 0x000000ff;        
    header[4] = (file_size >> 16) & 0x000000ff;        
    header[5] = (file_size >> 24) & 0x000000ff;        
    
    width = xsize;
    header[18] = width & 0x000000ff;
    header[19] = (width >> 8) &0x000000ff;
    header[20] = (width >> 16) &0x000000ff;
    header[21] = (width >> 24) &0x000000ff;
     
    height = ysize;
    header[22] = height &0x000000ff;
    header[23] = (height >> 8) &0x000000ff;
    header[24] = (height >> 16) &0x000000ff;
    header[25] = (height >> 24) &0x000000ff;
    sprintf(fname_bmp, "%s.bmp", filename);
    FILE *fp; 
    if (!(fp = fopen(fname_bmp, "wb")))
    {    
        return -1;
    }        
    fwrite(header, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, fp);
    fwrite(image, sizeof(unsigned char), (size_t)(long)(xsize * 3 + FillingByte)*ysize, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

unsigned char *array_to_raw_image(const RGB* InputData, const int xsize, const int ysize)
{
    unsigned char FillingByte;
    FillingByte = bmp_filling_byte_calc(xsize);
    unsigned char *output;
    output = (unsigned char*)malloc((xsize * 3 + FillingByte) * ysize * sizeof(unsigned char));
    if(output == NULL)
    {    
        printf("Memory allocation error!");
        return NULL;
    }
    for(int y = 0;y < ysize;y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0;x < (xsize * 3 + FillingByte);x++)
        {
            output[y * (xsize * 3 + FillingByte) + x] = 0;
        }
    }
    for(int y = 0;y<ysize;y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0;x<xsize;x++)
        {
            output[3*(y * xsize + x) + y * FillingByte + 2]
            = InputData[y*xsize + x].R;
            output[3*(y * xsize + x) + y * FillingByte + 1]
            = InputData[y*xsize + x].G;
            output[3*(y * xsize + x) + y * FillingByte + 0]
            = InputData[y*xsize + x].B;
        }
    }
    return output;
}

unsigned char bmp_filling_byte_calc(const unsigned int xsize)
{
    unsigned char filling_bytes;
    filling_bytes = ( xsize % 4);
    return filling_bytes;
}


unsigned char *bubble_sort_uchar(   const unsigned char *data_input,
                                    const unsigned long long int data_input_count,
                                    const bool mode)
{
    unsigned char *output;
    output = (unsigned char*)malloc( data_input_count * sizeof(unsigned char) );
    for(unsigned long long int y=0;y < data_input_count;y++)
    {
        output[y] = data_input[y];
    }
    for(unsigned long long int x = 1; x < data_input_count; x++)
    {
        for(unsigned long long int y = 0; y < data_input_count - x; y++)
        {
            if( mode == 0 )
            {
                if(output[y] > output[y + 1])
                {
                    unsigned char temp;
                    temp = output[y];
                    output[y] = output[y + 1];
                    output[y + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
            else if( mode == 1 )
            {
                if(output[y] < output[y + 1])
                {
                    unsigned char temp;
                    temp = output[y];
                    output[y] = output[y + 1];
                    output[y + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

If there is any possible improvement, please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Thou shalt not cast `malloc`. It is redundant (if you `#include <stdlib.h>`), and may lead to hard-to-find bugs (if you don't).
- `sort_array` is allocated at each iteration, yet never `free`d.

  That said, I don't see why it needs `malloc` at all. Declare it statically

  ```
    unsigned char sort_array[9];
  ```
- DRY. The code for R, G, and B channels, thrice repeated, cries to become a function. Consider defining `RGB` as

  ```
    typedef struct {
        unsigned char channel[3];
    } RGB;
  ```

  and writing the `else` clause as

  ```
    for (int color = 0; color < 3; i++) {
        output[i].channel[color] = median_filter_channel(image, i, xsize, color);
    }
  ```

Answer (score 5):

You’ve got some excellent answers commenting on the code itself. I am here to comment on the *algorithm*.

It is really hard to implement a color median filter. The median is defined for a set of scalar values (and thus it is straight-forward to define a median filter that works on a gray-scale image). But the median of a set of 3-vectors (such as RGB pixel values) is not well defined. You cannot meaningfully sort vectors.

You have implemented a marginal median—you compute the median for each of the components of the vector separately. The resulting value is typically not one of the input vectors. This means that your median filter is creating new colors that do not appear in the input image. For example, the marginal median of a equal combination of pure green, red and blue pixels is black! And the marginal median of an equal combination of pure magenta, cyan and yellow pixels is white!

There exists a vector median. It selects the input vector that has the minimal distance to all other inputs (using either the sum of distances or sum of square distances). This is a lot more expensive to compute than the marginal median, and there is no guarantee that the vector median is actually “in the middle” of the set. But at least you don’t introduce new colors.

You can define a consistent ordering of RGB colors, for example using dictionary sort, or sorting on brightness only and ignoring color, or some other system. No matter how you define the ordering, there is no guarantee that the result of your median computation is meaningful.

Finally, you can convert from RGB to another color space, and there use a dictionary sort. The same issues as above apply.

So, I have no good solution for you. It depends very much on the application which solution is most suitable. For “salt and pepper noise”, the marginal median and the sorting on brightness alone are reasonable solutions.

Answer (score 3):

**`int` vs. `size_t` math**

```
...,const int xsize,const int ysize) ...
output = (RGB*)malloc(xsize * ysize * sizeof(RGB));
//                    int   * int
```

`size_t` math typically exceeds `int` (and maybe `unsigned`) math and may handle `int` overflow of `xsize * ysize`.

Consider dropping the unneeded cast, re-order and size to the referenced data, rather than type.

```
output = malloc(sizeof *output * xsize * ysize);  // Uses size_t multiplication

// RGBImage1.IMAGE_DATA = (RGB*)malloc(RGBImage1.XSIZE * RGBImage1.YSIZE * sizeof(RGB));
RGBImage1.IMAGE_DATA = malloc(sizeof *RGBImage1.IMAGE_DATA * RGBImage1.XSIZE * RGBImage1.YSIZE);
//                            size_t                       * int(converted to size_t)
```

**`const` parameters**

This is **not** about the `const` in `const RGB *`.

Curious code uses `const int xsize`, but not `const RGB * const image` as neither `xsize` nor `RGB` changes.

If one is using `const` to help prevent changes to unchanging parameters, be consistent.

```
// RGB *MedianFilter33(const RGB *image,const int xsize,const int ysize)
RGB *MedianFilter33(const RGB * const image, const int xsize, const int ysize)
```

IMO: these `const` tend to be more error prone/obfuscation than worth it as they are noise in a `.h` function declaration.

```
// Suggested:
RGB *MedianFilter33(const RGB *image, int xsize, int ysize)
```

**`int` vs. `long long`**

Code curiously uses `long long i` below versus `int i`.

```
... const int xsize,const int ysize ...
for(long long int i = 0; i <(xsize * ysize); i++) // Why long long int?
```

Should `xsize * ysize` exceed `INT_MAX`, result is *undefined behavior* and so nothing is gained by making `i` an `long long`.  Code could compute the product using `long long` math`:

```
// A little better
for(long long int i = 0; i <(1LL * xsize * ysize); i++)
```

For array sizing consider `size_t` and a C2x principle: put [dimensions first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x#Features).

```
// RGB *MedianFilter33(const RGB *image,const int xsize,const int ysize)
RGB *MedianFilter33(size_t xsize, size_t ysize, const RGB *image)
```

Likewise problem with

```
unsigned char header[54];
...
unsigned long output;
output = header[18] + (header[19] << 8) + ( header[20] << 16) + ( header[21] << 24);
```

`header[18] + (header[19] << 8) + ( header[20] << 16) + ( header[21] << 24)` is computed using `int` math.

Alternative:

```
unsigned long output = header[18] + 
    ((unsigned long)header[19] << 8) + 
    ((unsigned long)header[20] << 16) + 
    ((unsigned long)header[21] << 24);
```

Here also, I'd consider `size_t` rather than `unsigned long`.

Comment: A common, and useful, practice is to use `const` where possible and useful in the *definition*, but only the type (without top-level `const`) in other declarations (e.g. in a header file).

Comment: @TobySpeight I respectively disagree that  "use const where possible".  IMO not worthy the noise/clarity ratio.  Perhaps there is a better forum than comments here to hash that out?

Comment: "where possible" is too strong.  "Where you would declare a similar local variable `const`" is probably more apt.  Main point was don't write it in non-defining declarations.  (BTW, ITYM "respectfully"?)

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, respectfully.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you for the answer. After I tried to remove the unneeded cast you mentioned. It can be compiled successfully in gcc, but clang says "error: assigning to 'RGB *' from incompatible type 'void *'"

Comment: @JimmyHu `"error: assigning to 'RGB *' from incompatible type 'void *'"` --> You are likely compiling in another language like C++.  Try compiling in C instead.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you for letting me know the difference. It can be compiled successfully in clang, not clang++.

Answer (score 1):

`buble_sort_uchar` allocates memory, and returns a pointer to it, but the pointer is never freed. And in two cases (G and B channels), the returned pointer isn't saved so the sort effectively does nothing except leak memory.

Similarly, the memory allocated in `MedianFilter33` for `sort_array` is never freed.

Comment: And neither of those actually require allocation - local variables should be fine in both cases.